# "CSV file does not exist" for a filename with embedded quotes

Tags: python, csv, pandas, atom-editor

I am currently learning Pandas for data analysis and having some issues reading a csv file in Atom editor.

When I am running the following code:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("FBI-CRIME11.csv")

print(df.head())
```

I get an error message, which ends with

> OSError: File b'FBI-CRIME11.csv' does not exist

Here is the directory to the file: /Users/alekseinabatov/Documents/Python/"FBI-CRIME11.csv".

When i try to run it this way:

```
df = pd.read_csv(Users/alekseinabatov/Documents/Python/"FBI-CRIME11.csv")
```

I get another error:

> NameError: name 'Users' is not defined

I have also put this directory into the "Project Home" field in the editor settings, though I am not quite sure if it makes any difference.

I bet there is an easy way to get it to work. I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
df = pd.read_csv("Users/alekseinabatov/Documents/Python/FBI-CRIME11.csv")
```

or maybe

```
df = pd.read_csv('Users/alekseinabatov/Documents/Python/"FBI-CRIME11.csv"')
```

(If the file name has quotes)

Comment: The first suggestion should work if you tweak it to include the reference to the root directory, i.e.: `pd.read_csv("/Users/alekseinabatov/Documents/Python/FBI-CRIME11.csv")`. The file name should not have quotation symbols in it.

Comment: the following code worked: pd.read_csv("/Users/alekseinabatov/Documents/Python/FBI-CRIM‌​E11.csv"). Thank you so much!

Comment: Any idea how i can make this a default directory for the future projects?

Comment: @AlekseiNabatov A pythonic way is declare a constant containing the path: `PATH = 'Users/alekseinabatov/Documents/Python/'` and then `pd.read_csv(PATH + 'FBI-CRIME11.csv')`.

If this path will be shared across projects, you can use an environment variable containing the path ;-)

Comment: in my case changed ev = pd.read_csv(join(sub,'evaluation.csv')) -> ev = pd.read_csv(join(sub,"evaluation.csv"))

Answer (score 5):

Just referring to the filename like

```
df = pd.read_csv("FBI-CRIME11.csv")
```

generally only works if the file is in the same directory as the script.

If you are using windows, make sure you specify the path to the file as follows:

```
PATH = "C:\\Users\\path\\to\\file.csv"
```

Comment: Using Mac actually. I was wondering how to set this directory as default one so I do not have to write the whole path every time I do input/output operations.

Answer (score 3):

Had an issue with the path, it turns out that you need to specify the first '/' to get it to work!
I am using VSCode/Python on macOS

Answer (score 3):

I also experienced the same problem I solved as follows:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\path\\to\\file.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

Being on **jupyter notebook** it works for me including the relative path only. For example:

```
df = pd.read_csv ('file.csv')
```

But, for example, in **vscode** I have to put the complete path:

```
df = pd.read_csv ('/home/code/file.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing '/' before Users. I assume that you are using a MAC guessing from the file path names. You root directory is '/'.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but it was happening because my file was called "geo_data.csv.csv" - new laptop wasn't showing file extensions, so the name issue was invisible in Windows Explorer. 
Very silly, I know, but if this solution doesn't work for you, try that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just change the CSV file name. Once I changed it for me, it worked fine. Previously I gave `data.csv` then I changed it to `CNC_1.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os

base =os.path.normpath(r"path")



with open(base, 'r') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    data=[]
    for row in readCSV:
        data.append(row)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:],columns=data[0][0:15])
    print(df)


This reads in the file , delimit by |, and appends to list which is converted to a pandas df (taking 15 columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your source file is saved in .csv format. I tried all the steps of adding the full path to the file, including and deleting the header=0, adding skiprows=0  but nothing works as I saved the excel file(data file) in workbook format and not in CSV format. so keep in mind to first check your file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Adnane's answer helped me.

Here's my full code on mac, hope this helps someone. All my csv files are saved in /Users/lionelyu/Documents/Python/Python Projects/

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

path = '/Users/lionelyu/Documents/Python/Python Projects/'

aapl = pd.read_csv(path + 'AAPL_CLOSE.csv',index_col='Date',parse_dates=True)
cisco = pd.read_csv(path + 'CISCO_CLOSE.csv',index_col='Date',parse_dates=True)
ibm = pd.read_csv(path + 'IBM_CLOSE.csv',index_col='Date',parse_dates=True)
amzn = pd.read_csv(path + 'AMZN_CLOSE.csv',index_col='Date',parse_dates=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run "pwd" command first in cli to find out what is your current project's direction and then add the name of the file to your path!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os 
cd = os.getcwd()
dataset_train = pd.read_csv(cd+"/Google_Stock_Price_Train.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just removed .csv from the end. I am using ubuntu.

```
pd.read_csv("/home/mypc/Documents/pcap/s2csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we ignore a little bit issue which is not a **Python** or **IDE** fault
its logical error 
We assumed a file .csv which is not a .csv file its a Excell Worksheet file have a look

---

[image: Tiktok file which is worksheet file not a CSV file Shown in Green border]

---

When you try to open that file using Import compiler will through the error 
have a look
[image]

### To Resolve the issue

open your Target file into Microsoft Excell and save that file in .csv format
it is important to note that Encoding is important because it will help you to open the file when you try to open it with

```
with open('YourTargetFile.csv','r',encoding='UTF-8') as file:
```

[image]

So you are set to go 
now Try to open your file as this

```
import csv
with open('plain.csv','r',encoding='UTF-8') as file:
load = csv.reader(file)
for line in load:
    print(line)
```

Here is the Output
[image: Plain.csv File Running]

Answer (score -1):

What works for me is

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('FBI_CRIME11.csv')
```

Highlight it and press enter. It also depends on the IDE you are using. I am using Anaconda Spyder or Jupiter.

Answer (score -2):

I am using a Mac. I had the same problem wherein .csv file was in the same folder where the python script was placed, however, Spyder still was unable to locate the file. I changed the file name from capital letters to all small letters and it worked.